# use python __call__ magic method to replicate `def` within class

Tags: python, functional-programming, closures, decorator, magic-methods

Suppose we have a class which acts as a decorator

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.variable1 = 1
        self.variable2 = 2
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
```

It cannot be readily used on an instance method

```
class Bar:
    @Foo
    def dance(self):
        return 0
Bar().dance()  # TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Is it possible to make `dance()` behave just like a built-in boundmethod, but also allow it to have additional variables like `Bar().dance.variable1`?

A related question: we know the undecorated `Bar().__dance__` has attribute `__self__` pointing to the `Bar` object. Is it possible to make use of `__self__` in `variable1`?

Comment: If you want to make use of `self` in `variable1`, use `@property`.

Comment: @Barmar I would like to make `variable1` a property of `Foo` object. As suggested by @chepner, `MethodType(Foo(dance))` gives you an object which simultaneously has `__self__` (which is a `Bar`) and `variable1` (which is an attribute of `Foo`). I would like `variable1` to depend on `__self__`, not `self`.

Answer (score 2):

`Foo` needs to be a descriptor, with a `__get__` method similar to that defined by `function`. Adapted from https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.variable1 = 1
        self.variable2 = 2

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return types.MethodType(self, obj)
```

The `__self__` attribute you mentioned is an attribute of the `MethodType` value returned by `__get__`, not of `dance`. (This is because `Bar().dance` does *not* evaluate to the *function* `dance`, but to the return value of the `__get__` method.)

It's probably simpler to just not use a class as a decorator, and use a function (which is already a descriptor) instead.

```
def Foo(f):
    def _(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return _
```